# Web Dynpro for ABAP Explanation Text (Green Underline) not working for certain users

Tags: abap, webdynpro

I have recently added Explanation text to certain fields on the SRM Contract screen (both standard and cusom fields).  The user that I unit tested with worked fine, however most other users do not work.  After investigation I've found that it is not just the Explanation Text that I've added, but all Explanation Text that is missing.

[image]

According to the [sap help entry](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_crm70/helpdata/EN/45/11e345459d7201e10000000a155369/content.htm) the behaviour is similar to what I would expect for **Help mode = off**.

Is it possible to turn Help mode on or off on a per user (or role) basis, and where should I look to find this?

Answer (score 1):

you already found it: SAP Help says:
"You can activate the help mode either in the personal settings in the portal or in the associated URL Parameter" ... means in personal Settings, but I feel that you want it globally not on personal base or in the associated URL Parameter. The latter means you'll have to find the application in the Portal Content, there you can find URL Parameter and i would try adding HELPMODE=ON... does this help you? 
start by rightclicking you application "Technical Help" or "..Help" and see what application you are looking for. Then Google the application and add +"Portal Content", I think then you'll find it.
regards, zy